# How to get value from mono

Tags: java, functional-programming, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

Im really new with reactive programming.
Im trying to figure out what to do here

i have written the following code:

```
templateService.getTemplate(id)
     .map(this::setTemplate)
     .map(c -> convertDTOToBO(dto, c))
     .flatMap(templateService::toPdf)
     .map(content -> ResponseEntity.ok()
     .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"test_" + NAMEPROPERTYHERE + ".pdf\"")
           .body(content));
```

I need to get a value that is on the object that returns from  `templateService.getTemplateById(id)`, need to take the property 'name' to put on the 'filename' (where i write NAMEPROPERTYHERE). I just cant figure out how i can do it.

the problem is that when it gets to the last map, the object is not the same anymore and i cant get the value i need.

Im so used to the traditional way of programming that i can only think to pass it to a variable.. what the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could just shift logic "one-level down" to get access to the template

```
templateService.getTemplate(id)
        .map(template ->
                setTemplate(template)
                    .map(c -> convertDTOToBO(dto, c))
                    .flatMap(templateService::toPdf)
                    .map(content -> ResponseEntity.ok()
                            .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"test_" + template.getName() + ".pdf\"")
                            .body(content))
        );
```